# How to fix Entity Framework Core cascade delete error in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, cascading-deletes

In the application I am currently working on, I have a `Member` data model and an `Address` data model that can exist independently from each other.  I do not want to delete the `Address` when a `Member` gets a new address. I only need to delete the relationship record from the many-to-many join table, `MemberAddressJoin`.

I am getting this error when I run the `update-database` command to build the database:

> Failed executing DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> CREATE TABLE [AddressMember] (
> [AddressesId] int NOT NULL,
> [MembersId] int NOT NULL,
> CONSTRAINT [PK_AddressMember] PRIMARY KEY ([AddressesId], [MembersId]),
> CONSTRAINT [FK_AddressMember_Addresses_AddressesId] FOREIGN KEY ([AddressesId]) REFERENCES [Addresses] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
> CONSTRAINT [FK_AddressMember_Members_MembersId] FOREIGN KEY ([MembersId]) REFERENCES [Members] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
> );

How do I configure Entity Framework Core to delete only the record from the `MemberAddressJoin` table and leave the `Addresses` and `Members` tables alone?

These are the data models in a many-to-many relationship:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Application.Data.Models
{    
    public class Member
    {         
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
       
        [PersonalData]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        
        [PersonalData]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public string PreferredName { get; set; }
        
        [PersonalData]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public int Age { get; set; }       

        // Many-to-many navigation
        public virtual ICollection<MemberAddressJoin> MemberAddressJoins { get; set; }                
        // Many-to-many skip navigation
        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Application.Data.Models
{
    public class MemberAddressJoin
    {
        [Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        // FK Many-to-many
        public int? MemberId {get; set; }
        // FK Many-to-many navigation
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

        // FK Many-to-many
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        // FK Many-to-many navigation
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Application.Data.Models
{
    [Table("Addresses")]
    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
       
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        
        public string Line3 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        // Many-to-one, Address is child
        public int CountyId { get; set; }
        public virtual County County { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //// Many-to-one, Address is child
        //public State State { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }        

        [Required]
        public bool IsMailingAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsResidenceAddress { get; set; }

        // One-to-one, Address is parent
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

        // Many-to-many
        public ICollection<MemberAddressJoin> MemberAddressJoins { get; set; }
        // Many-to-many skip navigation
        public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }


        public override bool Equals(object o)
        {
            var other = o as Location;
            return other?.Name == Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        public override string ToString() => Name;


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get
            {
                string name = string.Empty;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Line1))
                    name = Line1;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Line2))
                    name = $"{name}, {Line2}";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Line3))
                    name = $"{name}, {Line3}";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))
                    name = $"{name}, {City}";

                if (County.State is not null)
                    name = $"{name}, {County.State.Name}";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Zipcode))
                    name = $"{name}, {Zipcode}";

                return name;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make multiple changes to my data models to get rid of this error and to achieve the desired result. The following allows me to delete the relationship entity, `MemberAddressJoin`, without creating a cascading delete to either `Member` or `Address`.

For the join entity (`MemberAddressJoin`) I needed to:

- remove the nullable operator from the foreign keys `?`.^
- remove the virtual accessor from the foreign key navigation.^
- add fluent api code to the entity configuration class (`MemberAddressJoinConfig.cs`) to turn of delete cascading for both the Member and Address entities.^^

For the `Member` data model class I needed to:

- add fluent api code to the entity configuration class (`MemberConfig.cs`) to designate the join table as `MemberAddressJoins`.^

For the `Address` data model class I needed to:

- add fluent api code to the entity configuration class (`AddressConfig.cs`) to designate the join table as `MemberAddressJoins`.^

This configuration allows me to delete the relationship entity, `MemberAddressJoin`, between `Member` and `Address` without either `Member` or `Address` being effected.

*^ related to the error fix*

*^^ related to turning of cascading delete*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Application.Data.Models
{    
    public class Member
    {         
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
       
        [PersonalData]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        
        [PersonalData]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public string PreferredName { get; set; }
        
        [PersonalData]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public int Age { get; set; }       

        // Many-to-many navigation
        public virtual ICollection<MemberAddressJoin> MemberAddressJoins { get; set; }                
        // Many-to-many skip navigation
        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Application.Data.Models
{
    public class MemberAddressJoin
    {
        [Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        // FK Many-to-many
        public int MemberId {get; set; }
        // FK Many-to-many navigation
        public Member Member { get; set; }

        // FK Many-to-many
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        // FK Many-to-many navigation
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Application.Data.Models
{
    [Table("Addresses")]
    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
       
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        
        public string Line3 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        // Many-to-one, Address is child
        public int CountyId { get; set; }
        public virtual County County { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //// Many-to-one, Address is child
        //public State State { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }        

        [Required]
        public bool IsMailingAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsResidenceAddress { get; set; }

        // One-to-one, Address is parent
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

        // Many-to-many
        public ICollection<MemberAddressJoin> MemberAddressJoins { get; set; }
        // Many-to-many skip navigation
        public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }


        public override bool Equals(object o)
        {
            var other = o as Location;
            return other?.Name == Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        public override string ToString() => Name;


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get
            {
                string name = string.Empty;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Line1))
                    name = Line1;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Line2))
                    name = $"{name}, {Line2}";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Line3))
                    name = $"{name}, {Line3}";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))
                    name = $"{name}, {City}";

                if (County.State is not null)
                    name = $"{name}, {County.State.Name}";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Zipcode))
                    name = $"{name}, {Zipcode}";

                return name;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using PartyTime.Data.Models;

namespace PartyTime.Data.EntityConfigurations
{
    internal class MemberAddressConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MemberAddressJoin>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MemberAddressJoin> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(ma => new { ma.MemberId, ma.AddressId });

            builder.HasOne(ma => ma.Member)
                .WithMany(m => m.MemberAddresseJoins)
                .HasForeignKey(ma => ma.MemberId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            builder.HasOne(ma => ma.Address)
                .WithMany(a => a.MemberAddresseJoins)
                .HasForeignKey(ma => ma.AddressId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using PartyTime.Data.Models;

namespace PartyTime.EntityConfigurations
{
    class AddressConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Address> builder)
        {
            builder.HasMany(x => x.Members)
                .WithMany(y => y.Addresses)
                .UsingEntity<MemberAddresJoins>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using PartyTime.Data.Models;

namespace PartyTime.EntityConfigurations
{
    class MemberConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Member>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Member> builder)
        {
            builder.HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
                .WithMany(y => y.Members)
                .UsingEntity<MemberAddresJoins>();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Juding from your message,it created another tabel  named of `AddressMember` instead of `MemberAddressJoin` to hold the relationship between  `Member` and `Address`(If you still have problem,please show the detailed message)

You could try configure as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-navigations-to-join-entity) to avoid this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasMany(x=>x.Addresses).WithMany(y=>y.Members).UsingEntity<MemberAddressJoin>();
```

Check your migrationsnapshot file:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("xx.MemberAddressJoin", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("xx.Address", "Address")
                        .WithMany("MemberAddressJoins")
                        .HasForeignKey("AddressId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("xx.Member", "Member")
                        .WithMany("MemberAddressJoins")
                        .HasForeignKey("MemberId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Address");

                    b.Navigation("Member");
                });
```

Set DeleteBehavior.Cascade here is OK,it won't delete `Address` or `Member` record when you delete `MemberAddressJoin`.When you delete the record of `Address` or `Member`,related `MemberAddressJoin` would also be deleted

And I noticed most of your properties are not nullable,you may have to set the nevigation property nullable to avoid cascading-delete,you could check  this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) for more details

> The default for required relationships like this is Cascade.
>
> Using anything other than cascade delete for required relationships
> will result in an exception when SaveChanges is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are correct that the Entity Framework is creating a new table called AddressMember instead of MemberAddressJoin. What I need to know is why is it doing it? or most importantly how to fix it? I have already been following the documentation you linked.

Comment: It's conversion for relationship,you could check this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions#many-to-many

Comment: Have you add migration again?If it still create AddressMember table after  you configured .UsingEntity<MemberAddressJoin>(); please show your dbcontext so that I could reproduce your issue on my side

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it did have part of the solution. I appreciate the time you spent helping me.